# How to change Windows 7 date format?

Tags: windows-7, date-format

Is it possible to configure Windows 7 to use YYYY-MM-DD instead of DD/MM/YYYY as the date format? How? Where?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

tl;dr

Go to Start > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options.

Here you can configure long and short date options on the Formats tab. Click additional settings to customize the formate more under the Date tab

**Edit: Updated with more detail:**

### Changing Date Format in Windows 7

1. Click `Start` and enter `Control Panel`

   [image]
2. Enter `Regional and Language Options` (select the `Large Icons` or `Small Icons` view to see this particular icon).

   [image]
3. Check the dropdown menu on the formats tab for `Short date` and `Long date`. See if there's a format that takes your fancy.

   [image]
4. If not, make your own. Click the `Additional settings` button at the bottom right corner of the window
5. Click on the Date tab. Here you can customize the format to whatever you wish. The notations are also given on this screen.
   [image]

I hope this more detailed answer helps someone in the future. Apologies for the screens as VirtualBox isn't the best with them. Feel free to update with some better ones

Answer (score 0):

More info:

1) You can go directly to "Control Panel", "Region" running: Intl.cpl

2) If you change the "Language" in "Format", it automatically changes the date format.

Extracted from here: http://www.sysadmit.com/2015/11/windows-cambiar-formato-fecha-al-ingles.html